# Python error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Tags: python, build, python-netifaces

When i try install netifaces-0.11.0 from source code in windows 10 i get error:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

How to install offline Microsoft C++ Build Tools?

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 1):

You need download Visual Studio Installer, and select these options:
[image]