# tifffiles package via pip - Cannot open include file: 'io.h No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

Windows 7, Python 3.6.0 here.

I was unable to bypass the hard-set pixel limit for opencv-python to read images, so somebody suggested using tifffiles to read large images into memory.

So I am now tring to acquire tifffiles 0.11.0 via pip.

(https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/0.11.0/)

Originally the error I got from pip was that I am missing "microsoft visual c++ 14.0", so after much digging, I found the following:

([Python error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75398486/python-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-get-it-with-mic))

I followed the advice of the reply (user: "sosnus"), and installed the required bits and pieces. A reboot or two later, and I am back to pip, trying to acquire tifffiles. I am now met with another error:

[image]

I can confirm, I do not have that file... how I can get it, I don't know. Apparently "io.h" is missing (curiously, if you place an io.h file --from elsewhere-- into the path mentioned, it will then complain about an "errno.h" also being missing), and as I don't have any errno.h files on my PC, I couldn't experiment with supplying this.

What can I do to get this sorted? Getting "microsoft visual c++ 14.0" was already painful enough, I don't understand why this package has to be awkward when none of the other packages I ever downloaded put me through such hoops.

Any help would be appreciated...!